# System.Text.UTF8Encoding From VBScript

Tags: .net, character-encoding, vbscript

How would do you call GetBytes (of System.Text.UTF8Encoding) from VBScript?

You [can use the .NET Framework from VBScript](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.01.heyscriptingguy.aspx) as [its exposed to COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx), but I haven't come across good documentation/manuals.

Comment: Time anachronism, dinosaur-and-human-movie style.  You can write a [ComVisible] class to set the time machine back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for equivalent in VBScript, you can do it using Ado Stream :

```
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Dim adoStr, bytesthroughado
Set adoStr = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
    adoStr.Charset = "utf-8"
    adoStr.Open
    adoStr.WriteText "你好Ğ"
    adoStr.Position = 0 'reset position
    adoStr.Type = adTypeBinary
    adoStr.Position = 3 'skip bom
    bytesthroughado = adoStr.Read 'get bytes
    WScript.Echo LenB(bytesthroughado) 'length
    adoStr.Close
Set adoStr = Nothing
```

It's possible to access some .Net components (from mscorlib) from VBScript.

```
Dim encoding, bytesthroughdotnet
Set encoding = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    bytesthroughdotnet = encoding.GetBytes_4("你好Ğ") 'get bytes
    WScript.Echo LenB(bytesthroughdotnet) 'length
Set encoding = Nothing
```

Comment: How do you know to use "_4" in GetBytes_4 ?

Comment: @user389823 I increase the suffix until find the proper method. Unfortunately the order of suffixes does not match .Net overload list. I would like to listen if someone really knows.

Comment: I've asked the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755263/determining-net-method-suffix-number-in-vbscript-com . Thanks again, (I originally only went up to _3)!